# MSSQL: substring value using parameter's internal value

Tags: sql, sql-server

i have two variables. 
first variable `@WhereClause` contain the value:
 `c1='v111' and c2='v222' and c3='v333' and c4='v444'`.

second variable `@ConditionFields` contain the value: `c2,c4`.

Now ,how can i get only the value of c2 and c4. 
like `@NewWhereClause` value will be: `c2='v222' and c4='v444'`. please help.

Comment: Are you trying to parse the @WhereClause string for the values in them?  If so, why?

Comment: what do you mean by "get only the value of c2 and c4"? Can you please post your whole query.

Comment: If these are being passed from external code, I'd recommend replacing them with table-valued parameters. If they're internal to the code you're working on, I'd recommend replacing them with table variables. Either way, I'd recommend trying to work with structured data over trying to do complex string manipulation every time.

Answer (score 0):

This might seem like an odd way to do it, but it works -- I'm sure this can be optimized as well, and there are several different ways to "Split" strings, I just thought this was a pretty cool one.

```
DECLARE @WhereClause varchar(MAX)
DECLARE @NewWhereClause varchar(MAX)
DECLARE @ConditionFields varchar(MAX)
DECLARE @Delimiter char(1)
DECLARE @X xml
DECLARE @TempCondition varchar(MAX)
DECLARE @TempWhereClause varchar(MAX)

SET @WhereClause = 'c1=''v111'' and c2=''v222'' and c3=''v333'' and c4=''v444'''
SET @ConditionFields = 'c2,c4'
SET @Delimiter = ','
SET @NewWhereClause = ''

SELECT @X = CONVERT(xml,'<root><s>' + REPLACE(@ConditionFields,@Delimiter,'</s><s>') + '</s></root>')

DECLARE ColCursor CURSOR FOR 
SELECT [Value] = T.c.value('.','varchar(20)')
FROM @X.nodes('/root/s') T(c)
WHERE T.c.value('.','varchar(20)') <> ''

OPEN ColCursor   
FETCH NEXT FROM ColCursor INTO @TempCondition   

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0   
BEGIN   
    SELECT @TempWhereClause = SUBSTRING(@WhereClause, CHARINDEX(@TempCondition, @WhereClause), CHARINDEX(' ', @WhereClause))
    IF @NewWhereClause = ''
    BEGIN
        SET @NewWhereClause = @TempWhereClause
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        SET @NewWhereClause += ' and ' + @TempWhereClause
    END

    FETCH NEXT FROM ColCursor INTO @TempCondition   
END   

CLOSE ColCursor   
DEALLOCATE ColCursor

SELECT @NewWhereClause
```

Here is the [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/7617):

Comment: That's pretty nifty. All the use cases I tried work except for the scenario where you put in a condition value that does not exist in the WhereClause. When I do this it includes the first node regardless of what I put in. Try 'c1,c4,c6,c8' to see what I mean. Any changes you can make to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

First off I agree with the comments that have been left on the post; this implementation is pretty ugly. That said, I'm bored so here you go.

```
/*
This will work assuming your variable formats are always consistent with no leading or trailing spaces:
@WhereClause format (SingleValue:"c1='v111'"; MultipleValues:"c1='v111' and c2='v222' and x#='...' and 'c156='anything'"
@ConditionFields format (SingleValue:"c2"; MultipleValues:"c2,c4,c7,...,c156"
*/

Create  Function dbo.ApplyConditionFields (@WhereClause Varchar(Max), @ConditionFields Varchar(Max))
Returns Varchar(Max)
With    Execute As Caller
As
Begin
        Declare @output Varchar(Max)

        If      @WhereClause Like '%=%'
        Begin
                ;With   parsedWhere As
                (
                        Select  Left(@WhereClause,CharIndex('=',@WhereClause)-1) As parsedVar,
                                Substring(@WhereClause,CharIndex('=',@WhereClause)+1,CharIndex(' ',@WhereClause+' ')-CharIndex('=',@WhereClause)-1) As parsedVal,
                                LTrim(Replace(Right(@WhereClause+' and ',Len(@WhereClause+' and ')-CharIndex(' and ',@WhereClause + ' and ')+2),' and ',' ')) As rest
                        Union   All
                        Select  Left(rest,CharIndex('=',rest)-1) As parsedVar,
                                Substring(rest,CharIndex('=',rest)+1,CharIndex(' ',rest)-CharIndex('=',rest)-1) As parsedVal,
                                Right(rest,Len(rest)-CharIndex(' ',rest)+1) As rest
                        From    parsedWhere
                        Where   rest <> ' '
                ),      parsedFields As
                (
                        Select  Left(@ConditionFields+',',CharIndex(',',@ConditionFields + ',')-1) As parsedVar,
                                Right(@ConditionFields+',',Len(@ConditionFields+',')-CharIndex(',',@ConditionFields+',')) As rest
                        Union   All
                        Select  Left(rest,CharIndex(',',rest + ',')-1) As parsedVar,
                                Right(rest,Len(rest)-CharIndex(',',rest+',')) As rest
                        From    parsedFields
                        Where   rest <> ''
                )   
                Select  @output = Coalesce(@output+' and ','')+pw.parsedVar+'='+pw.parsedVal
                From    parsedWhere pw
                Join    parsedFields pf
                        On  pw.parsedVar = pf.parsedVar
        End

        Return(@output)
End
```